# Azure Enterprise Application: Propagating changes in grants in multi-tenant application

Tags: azure, permissions, multi-tenant, microsoft-graph-api

I have successfully built and used an Azure multi-tenant application that uses MS-Graph.

I have now added one more graph api to the Application grant list.  I have tested it in my own tenant.  It works.

But when I look at the Permissions list in a different tenant (as an administrator of that other tenant), that new permission does not appear.  Days have gone by since I originally set it up.

How can I refresh the list in the other tenant?

Answer (score 0):

*A new permission does not appear* may be the target tenant will not be synchronized with the original tenant. Try to give permission on **Grant admin consent**and use URL then sign in with the target tenant's administrator account.

***Go to Azure portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> your application ->API permissions -> click select Grant admin consent***

[image]

Using URL :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}
```

For your Reference:

[Grant tenant-wide admin consent to an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent)

[permission to grant permissions to applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/custom-consent-permissions),